# Website/Files organisation for Ajax calls

Tags: php, ajax, file-organization

I am just getting started with Ajax, and I wonder how to organize my ajax scripts and php files (which process the ajax function).
With Php it was easy, one functions library functions.php with all my classes and methods that I can call whenever I need them.

My first reflex with Ajax was trying to call an already existing method inside a php class in order to process a contact form but I do believe this is impossible and I need a separate file to do this ?

My question is, do I need to create a different file.js for each ajax script and a file.php for each ajax call ?  It can get very messy with a few ajax functions  compared to php.

Is there a right way to organize this ?

Comment: theres no "right" way to do this its up to personall preference (if your not using a framework)

Answer (score 1):

You definitely should use a php framework !

It will help you to organize your code and will bring to you some helpful features like routing which would solve your problem.
You will define some roots, each linked to a specific controller and your code will be well organized.

I can recommend you Symfony2 : 
but there are a lot of which are able to do the job : 
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/

If your application is small you can have a look to silex which is a light version of Symfony

To define your urls, you can use a REST api which is a best practice.

I can understand that you find the learning curve of the frameworks difficult but you will not regret it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Frameworks are the first thing I stumbled upon when looking for ways to organize my files and definitely looks like a serious option for productivity motivations.  However I'm coding mostly for pleasure and learning purposes, I think it's a bit early for me to start using a framework as I prefere working around what I code myself to keep learning more and trying things out !

Comment: i think you should learn basic php before going near any framework